# How to configure Android Proguard for Apache Poi

Tags: java, android, apache-poi, proguard

I'm attempting to Obfuscate my application using ProGuard and every possible rule I could find, but I still get the following error

```
2019-05-23 12:01:48.138 24237-24299/omegaonedevelopers.client.omegamaps E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
    Process: omegaonedevelopers.client.omegamaps, PID: 24237
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(Unknown Source:0)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(SourceFile:63)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(SourceFile:12)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluate(SourceFile:2)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.BaseXSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCellValue(SourceFile:2)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.BaseFormulaEvaluator.evaluate(SourceFile:5)
        at omegaonedevelopers.client.omegamaps.MainActivity.a(SourceFile:53)
        at omegaonedevelopers.client.omegamaps.MainActivity.b(SourceFile:2)
        at omegaonedevelopers.client.omegamaps.MainActivity$a.doInBackground(SourceFile:4)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to verify instance (org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.EqualPtg) is a singleton.
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.put(SourceFile:4)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.initialiseInstancesMap(SourceFile:2)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.<clinit>(SourceFile:1)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(Unknown Source:0) 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(SourceFile:63) 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(SourceFile:12) 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluate(SourceFile:2) 
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.BaseXSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCellValue(SourceFile:2) 
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.BaseFormulaEvaluator.evaluate(SourceFile:5) 
        at omegaonedevelopers.client.omegamaps.MainActivity.a(SourceFile:53) 
        at omegaonedevelopers.client.omegamaps.MainActivity.b(SourceFile:2) 
        at omegaonedevelopers.client.omegamaps.MainActivity$a.doInBackground(SourceFile:4) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I have followed numerous posts on Stack overflow and added all of their fixes and followed their examples to the letter but none seem to fix my issue. After

This is the code that when run creates the problem

```java
private String getCellValue(FormulaEvaluator evaluator, Cell cell){
        String cellString = "";
        try {
            CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
            if(cellValue != null){
                switch (cellValue.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        cellString = Boolean.toString(cellValue.getBooleanValue());
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        cellString = Double.toString(cellValue.getNumberValue());
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        cellString = cellValue.getStringValue();
                        break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return cellString;
    }
```

My ProGuard Rules file:

```
-keep class .R
-keep class **.R$* {
    <fields>;
}

-keep class org.** { *; }
-keep class com.bea.xml.stream.**{*;}
-keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.** { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.** { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.**{*;}
-keep class com.apache.poi.** { *; }
-keep class schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.** {*;}




#  Optimize
-optimizations !field/*,!class/merging/*,*
-mergeinterfacesaggressively

# will keep line numbers and file name obfuscation
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# Apache POI
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn org.openxmlformats.schemas.**
-dontwarn org.etsi.**
-dontwarn org.w3.**
-dontwarn com.microsoft.schemas.**
-dontwarn com.graphbuilder.**
-dontnote org.apache.**
-dontnote org.openxmlformats.schemas.**
-dontnote org.etsi.**
-dontnote org.w3.**
-dontnote com.microsoft.schemas.**
-dontnote com.graphbuilder.**

-keeppackagenames org.apache.poi.ss.formula.function

-keep class com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.InputFactoryImpl
-keep class com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.OutputFactoryImpl
-keep class com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.EventFactoryImpl
-keep class org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder

-keep class schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sF1327CCA741569E70F9CA8C9AF9B44B2.TypeSystemHolder { public final static *** typeSystem; }

-keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.BuiltinSchemaTypeSystem { public static *** get(...); public static *** getNoType(...); }
-keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.PathResourceLoader { public <init>(...); }
-keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemCompiler { public static *** compile(...); }
-keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl { public <init>(...); public static *** get(...); public static *** getNoType(...); }
-keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderImpl { public static *** getContextTypeLoader(...); public static *** build(...); }
-keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale { public static *** streamToNode(...); public static *** nodeTo*(...); }
-keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Path { public static *** compilePath(...); }
-keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Query { public static *** compileQuery(...); }

-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CommentsDocument { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTAuthors { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTBooleanProperty { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTBookView { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTBookViews { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTBorder { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTBorders { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTBorderPr { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCell { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCellAlignment { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCellFormula { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCellStyleXfs { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCellXfs { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTColor { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCol { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCols { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTComment { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTComments { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCommentList { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTDrawing { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFill { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFills { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFont { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFonts { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFontName { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFontScheme { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFontSize { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTIntProperty { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTLegacyDrawing { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTNumFmts { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPatternFill { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPageMargins { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPane { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTRow { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSelection { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheet { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheetData { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheetDimension { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheetFormatPr { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheetView { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheetViews { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheets { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSst { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTStylesheet { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTRst { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorkbook { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorkbookPr { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorksheet { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTXf { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.SstDocument { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.StyleSheetDocument { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STCellType$Enum { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STCellFormulaType$Enum { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STXstring { *; }

-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CommentsDocumentImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTAuthorsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTBooleanPropertyImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTBookViewImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTBookViewsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTBorderImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTBordersImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTBorderPrImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTCellImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTCellAlignmentImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTCellFormulaImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTCellStyleXfsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTCellXfsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTColorImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTColImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTColsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTCommentImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTCommentsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTCommentListImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTDrawingImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTFillImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTFillsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTFontImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTFontsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTFontNameImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTFontSchemeImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTFontSizeImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTIntPropertyImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTLegacyDrawingImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTNumFmtsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTPatternFillImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTPageMarginsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTPaneImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTRowImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTSelectionImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTSheetImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTSheetDataImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTSheetDimensionImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTSheetFormatPrImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTSheetViewImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTSheetViewsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTSheetsImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTSstImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTStylesheetImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTRstImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTWorkbookImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTWorkbookPrImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTWorksheetImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTXfImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.SstDocumentImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.StyleSheetDocumentImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.STXstringImpl { *; }

-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.customProperties.impl.CTPropertiesImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.customProperties.impl.PropertiesDocumentImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.extendedProperties.impl.CTPropertiesImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.extendedProperties.impl.PropertiesDocumentImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.spreadsheetDrawing.impl.CTDrawingImpl { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.spreadsheetDrawing.impl.CTMarkerImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.office.office.impl.CTIdMapImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.office.office.impl.CTShapeLayoutImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.vml.impl.CTShadowImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.vml.impl.CTFillImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.vml.impl.CTPathImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.vml.impl.CTShapeImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.vml.impl.CTShapetypeImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.vml.impl.CTStrokeImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.vml.impl.CTTextboxImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.office.excel.impl.CTClientDataImpl { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.office.excel.impl.STTrueFalseBlankImpl { *; }
```

If it helps this is the part of the code where the exception is thrown in the POI OperationEvaluatorFactory.class

```java
private static void put(Map<OperationPtg, Function> m, OperationPtg ptgKey, Function instance) {
    Constructor<?>[] cc = ptgKey.getClass().getDeclaredConstructors();
    if (cc.length <= 1 && Modifier.isPrivate(cc[0].getModifiers())) {
      m.put(ptgKey, instance);
    } else {
      throw new RuntimeException("Failed to verify instance (" + ptgKey.getClass().getName() + ") is a singleton.");
    }
  }
```

I'm getting these errors at runtime and they only show up in release build, so it's safe to assume that ProGuard is my problem.

Comment: Do you get any solution?

Comment: No, I had to remove the code all together and ensure no functions were being used. :(